# sum of nodes greater than a number in BST

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

For a binary search tree structure in C that cannot be changed:

```
struct bstnode {
  int item;
  struct bstnode* left;
  struct bstnode* right;
};

struct bst {
  struct bstnode* root;
};
```

How can we find the sum of values that are greater than a number(num)?
(we cannot travel the whole tree or convert this bst to an array).
the function declaration is:

```
int sum_greater(struct bst * t, int num)
```

Basically, my method is to use recursion:
when num equals item in the current node, we sum the right part of this tree.
when num greater than item in the current node and node->right is greater than num, we sum the right part of this tree.
But I dont know how to deal with the situation when current node is less than num.

Comment: "my method is use recursion" --> post the code that you have used, even if it is failing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: When you say you "cannot travel the whole tree", I presume you mean that you must minimize the number of nodes traversed.  If *all* the values in it are greater than the target number, then that still means traversing the whole tree.

Comment: The key, then, is at each node to decide which children, if any, to traverse.  You can make that decision pretty simply based only on the current node's value and the threshold number.  For at least some of the nodes you do traverse, you'll still need to test whether to add the node's value to your sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making this a bit too complicated.  Your base case is hitting a leaf node (which you already know how to handle).  You have three recursion cases:

```
current > num
    result = current +
             recur on right child +
             recur on left  child
current = num
    result = current +
             recur on right child
current < num
    result = recur on right child

return result
```

All you can do is to prune off the left subtrees that are too small as you find them.  don't waste effort looking ahead: the recursion will handle that just fine.

Note that you *cannot* stop early dependent on the right child's value: that child may well have right-descendants with arbitrarily large values.

Comment: This appears amiss."find the sum of values that are greater than a `num`".  First line should be `current > num` .

Comment: if `current`  can appears more than once in the BST, then `current = num` needs to add both left and right.

Comment: OOOOOOPS!  Correcting the inequalities.

Comment: @chux: OP's discourse of the "equals" case suggests that duplication isn't an issue; that's why I left it as a trifurcate decision.

Answer (score 0):

So the user @Prune has already pointed out the idea which consists of getting ride of sub trees that are less than the desired value.

```
int sum_greater(struct bst * t, int num){

    struct bstnode *ptr = t->root;
    if(!ptr)
        return 0;

    struct bst right_tree = { t->root->right };
    struct bst left_tree = { t->root->left };

    if(ptr->item > num) 
        return ptr->item + \
            sum_greater(&left_tree, num) + \
                sum_greater(&right_tree, num);
    else // ptr->item =< num
        return sum_greater(&right_tree, num);
}
```

For a complete example, run the code from : [Full sum_greater code](https://pastebin.com/0UnfKvLT)

Answer (score 0):

> how to deal with the situation when current node is less than num.

Only add the *right* BST in that case, when current node is less than *or equal* to `num`.  Else add both left, right and the `->item`.

```
int BST_sum_gt(const struct bstnode* node, int num) {
  if (node == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (node->item > num) {
    return BST_sum_gt(node->left) + node->item + BST_sum_gt(node->left);
  }  
  return BST_sum_gt(node->left);
}

int sum_greater(const struct bst * t, int num) {
  return BST_sum_gt(t->root);
}
```

Or a less recursive approach

```
int BST_sum_gt(const struct bstnode* node, int num) {
  int sum = 0; 
  while (node) {
    if (node->item > num) {
      sum += BST_sum_gt(node->left) + node->item;
    }
    node = node->right;
  }  
  return sum;
}
```